# Why haven't my Birch and London plane tree leafed out yet

Tags: trees, plant-health

In the fall I bought a few trees from Arbor Day. I planted the birch and plane tree on the north side of my house and they haven't budded, bloomed, or leafed yet while my other trees have. I did the scratch test and they're still green under the bark although the plane tree's top did die back. I'm in Chicago zone 5b/6, we had a very mild winter so I don't know want the problem is

Comment: A picture of the tree would be very helpful to add to your question

Comment: What are the temperatures there? It should take a week or two to show any real growth if you've had a hard frost.

Answer (score 4):

- Option A; they are dead (don't go too hasty on this option, it might
  be wrong)
- Option B; they know, or think they know, something about your "mild
  winter" that you don't, and are biding their time, hoping to miss a late frost/freeze.